# Need some clarification for finding work for this problem!

Tags: integration, physics

Q.)The resistance of a packing material to a sharp object is given by:
$$F = 1.20 × 10^4 x^2$$ where x is the penetration depth. How much work has to
be done to force a sharp object a distance 5.00 mm into the material?

I get the fact that you have to use the work formula $$W=\int_i^f\vec{F}*\vec{dl}$$ 
and then you have to change from vectors to just plain numbers, so for this case its this multiplied by cos(0) or 1 which doesnt really matter for this problem. 
So when I did this problem my final answer ends up as $$30x^4$$ and x is replaced by 0.005 since im looking for the joules and I seem to end up with $$1.875*10^{-8}$$ so when I looked over the several possible answers for this question being
$$(A.) 1.88 × 10^{−6}J (B.) 60 J (C.) 1.50 × 10^{−3} J (D.) 7.50 × 10^{−6} J$$ Am I missing some steps or did I messed up along the way?

Comment: $W = 1.2\cdot 10^4 x^4/4$ where $x = 0.5\cdot 10^{-3}$.  Thus, $W=187.5\cdot 10^{-8} = 1.875\cdot 10^{-6} J$.

Comment: Oh right! I messed up on the integration part, I put a 2 instead of 4 for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: $dW=Fdl=1.2\cdot 10^4l^2\;dl$..... So $W=K+0.4\cdot 10^4 l^3.$